# PHP ldap_bind "exception"

Tags: php, yii, ldap

This is my code and it is working corrently.

```
$authenticated = ldap_bind($conn, $this->username . "@" . $servidor_dominio, $this->password);
```

The description of this function specifies that it returns bool. When the user types an incorrect combination of username and password I get an error from the server:

```
Error 500. ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Invalid credentials
```

This is truly a PHP Warning but it stops the execution of my app. It even shows the stack trace page (I'm working with Yii PHP Framework).

I tried capturing an exception putting the ldap_bind() call inside a try/catch block:

```
try {
    $authenticated = ldap_bind($conn, $this->username . "@" . $servidor_dominio, $this->password);
} catch (Exception $exc) {
    echo $exc->getTraceAsString();
}
```

It doesn't catch any exception and I'm still getting the same error:

```
Error 500 ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Invalid credentials
```

Can someone help me with this? It seems that my users miss types their login credentials too often ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply put an @ symbol in front of ldap_bind and then use the $authenticated variable to display back to the user if they authenticated correctly.

```
$authenticated = @ldap_bind($conn, $this->username . "@" . $servidor_dominio, $this->password);
```

Comment: Perfect!!! It solved it. Can you explain me this behaviour? The "@" was used for passing refferences to variables as far as I know. I'm right?

Comment: the @ symbol in PHP simply suppresses any error messages returned by that command. Since ldap_bind returns false when it doesn't succeed, you really don't need error messages on it unless you are doing troubleshooting on why it couldn't bind.

Comment: Simply suppressing errors will solve the immediate problem, but not the root cause. It's likely that this may generate hard to find bugs in the future.

Comment: @EnmanuelRivera I think you misunderstand how ldap_bind works or what the desired behavior is. If you don't suppress the error, you will never receive false back, but instead it will throw an exception instead which you would then have to catch and parse if you wanted to continue processing, such as in an invalid credentials situation. It's better, in my opinion, to ignore that error, and then if you need more specific information about a failure use `ldap_error`/`ldap_errno` functions to get more information about why exactly it failed.